# What is the best way to display a videostream in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a server that constantly sends out a video stream. It's just a constant stream of images actually.

I can display this stream in my browser by loading the following html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<h2>Video:</h2>
<img src='http://192.168.1.100:8081/' style='width:304px;height:228px;'>
</body></html>
```

Now I want to load this stream in a PyQt application that I'm building.
When I try this in QWebView, it doesn't load the image. I have also tried it with loading it into QPixmap. Nothing works.

So now I want to know, is there an easy way to display this stream in a QT widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while I found the solution. In this example I have a .ui template that I load first. In this window is a label called 'label', in which I want to load my stream. You will need openCV for this.

```
class videoThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self,address):
        super(videoThread,self).__init__()
        self.ip = address

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://"+ str(self.ip) +
            ":8081/?action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg")
        while cap.isOpened():
            _,frame = cap.read()
            # adjust width en height to the preferred values
            image = QImage(frame.tostring(),640,480,QImage.Format_RGB888)
                .rgbSwapped() 
            self.emit(SIGNAL('newImage(QImage)'), image)

class MyGui(QMainWindow):
    """
       My gui implementation 
    """
    def __init__(self,template):
        super(MyGui,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(template,self)

        #video stream
        self.video = videoThread("192.168.1.100")
        self.video.start()
        #my label is named label
        self.label.connect(self.video,SIGNAL('newImage(QImage)'),self.setFrame)

    def setFrame(self,frame):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(frame)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: can You please make it work on Python3? I have problem with emiting and connecting. I use: 
self.video.obrazek.connect(self.setFrame)

and 
obrazek = pyqtSignal(QImage)
self.obrazek.emit(image)